# Write a function int mystrlen(char *s) that returns the number of characters in a string wuthout strlen func

Tags: c

heres what i did, i just have ne error that i cant figure out.

```
int mystrlen(char string[])
{
 char string1[LENGHT], string2[LENGHT];
 int len1, len2;
 char newstring[LENGHT*2];

 printf("enter first string:\n");
 len1 = mystrlen(string1);
 printf("enter second string:\n");
 len2 = mystrlen(string2);

 if(len1 == EOF || len2 == EOF)
  exit(1);

 strcpy(newstring, string1);
 strcat(newstring, string2);

 printf("%s\n", newstring);

 return 0;
```

Comment: @henry: You can format your code by using code button (101010) in the question editor. Take care of this while posting.

Comment: Your missing a closing }

Comment: Also, you are calling mystrlen from mystrlen. That will cause StackOverflow due to infinite recusrsion.

Comment: Also you don't actually call any function that would get the input from the user.

Comment: why are you printing 'enter first string' when u r not taking any input from user ?

Comment: @henry, your code is a bit confusing, your title says one thing but the code something else.

Comment: `int mystrlen(char* s) { int n=0; while(*s++) ++n; return n; }`

Comment: Sorry but this is not http://debug-my-code-for-me.com

Answer (score 2):

Cheating, but follows your rules...

```
int mystrlen( char *s)
{
    return strchr( s, '\0') - s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You recursively call the same function on all branches. It ain't gonna work - the program will incur stack overflow and most likely crash big time.

You need to structure the program somehow like this:

```
int mystrlen(char string[])
{
    //compute length here
}

void testStuff()
{
    //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to read your program using [Pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) - It will probably be easier to understand then :)

1. Declare variables string1, string2, len1, len2, newstring
2. Print a message
3. 3 Go to 1
   3.1. Declare variables string1, string2, len1, len2, newstring
   3.2. Print a message
   3.3. Go to 3.1
   ...       3.3.1 Declare variables string1, string2, len1, len2, newstring
   ...       3.3.2 .....

You see the error? :)

Answer (score 0):

To come up with a solution to your problem, you must understand that in C a "string" is an array of characters terminated by '\0'. That should be enough to help you work through a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
int mystrlen(char string[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while(string[i] != '\0'){
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}
```